# Siegel's lemma for arbitary number field.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

I want to show a proposition related to Siegel's lemma:

> Let $K$ be a number field of degree $d$, $L_j = \sum_{i} a_{ij}X_i \in \mathcal{O}_K[X_1, \cdots, X_N] (j= 1, \cdots, M)$ linear forms in $K$ which is all independent, $A = H_K(\cdots, a_{ij}, \cdots)$, and assume $M \lt N$.
>   Then there exists nonzero $x \in \mathcal{O}_K^N$ such that for all $j$, $L_j(x) = 0$ and
>   $$ \prod_{v | \infty} \max_i |x_i|_v \le (cNA)^{\frac{M}{N-M}}, $$
>   where $c$ is a constant which depends only on $K$ and an integral basis of $K$.

In my text, Siegel's lemma says similar statement except that $M \lt N$ resp. $x \in \mathcal{O}_K^N$ resp. $ \prod_{v | \infty} \max_i |x_i|_v$ resp. $M/(N-M)$ in the proposition above, is replaced by $dM \lt N$ resp. $x \in \mathbb{Z}^N$ resp. $\max_i|x_i|$ resp $dM/(N-dM)$.
I think that Siegel's lemma in my text can't be extended to the proposition above.

And theorem 7 in [this pdf](http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/nbnfioulu-201512012187.pdf) also says the similar statement, but I think that it can't be extended, too.
So please show the proposition above, or give me some references.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I used lectures notes from Jan-Hendrik Evertse. You can find [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kM1ZAMP64vj8nOWXr5atVeT_Y0Ny69_d/view) page 50 for the Siegel's lemma for number fields and its proof.

Comment: I want solutions in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Please look at my statement carefully.